# Selenium WebDriver: Firefox browser shows the last visited page after login process

Tags: selenium, firefox

I use the following code:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();        
FirefoxProfile myProfile = profile.getProfile("MyProfile");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(myProfile);
```

I manually log in and navigate to a page other than Home Page.
Then execute the script. Firefox browser automatically shows the last visited page after successful login.

My requirement is, browser should show the Home Page after successful login. How to do this?

Comment: is it only on script execution or manually also?

Comment: This happens manually too.

Comment: Then there option which is checked to open last visited page. Please look for it and un check

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in other browsers like IE and/or Chrome? Are you seeing similar behavior?

Also, try clearing all the cookies with the below line

driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();

Comment: This happens with other browsers also. I had tried "driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()", but no luck.

Comment: Then it looks like a design default one. Doesn't look like an issue as you said in the above comment to @murali it also happens in manual run.